# Change Size of P Tag on One Page Template

Tags: tags, page-template, fonts

I have two blog types on my website (Blogs and Updates). I need to change the P tag font size in both page templates. These are the page templates that show a list of the posts/articles.
Blogs page (category.php) shows 10 articles at a time, and Updates page (index.php) shows 10 articles at a time.

For the Blog page (category.php):
I was able to change the font size on the category.php page template using

```
    body.category p {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    }
```

For the Updates page (index.php):
The paragraph string that shows the article excerpt

```
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

is inside of a div that is styled by class a named ".entry"...if that makes any difference.
I have tried several variations, but nothing has worked yet:

```
    .page-template-index .entry p {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    }

    body.index p {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    }

    entry.index p {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Did you try `.entry p`?

Comment: Holy cow lol....
.entry p worked!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I've added as an answer.  could you please mark it (green check to the left of the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entry is a class so when you're adding it to css you need to add a `.` in front.  just try doing this:

```
.entry p {
font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

See if that works.